# Best way to get some data and save to file, one method or two

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some code as follows:

In the PaymentsController:

```
[HttpPost]
public void GeneratePaymentData(IList<int> paymentIds)
{
  string paymentSummaryFileName;

  var results = _paymentsPort.GetPaymentData(paymentIds, out paymentSummaryFileName);

  _fileUtilities.SaveToFile(results, _appSettings.paymentFileSaveLocation, paymentSummaryFileName);
}
```

So what this does is goes off and gets some payment data and returns via the out parameter the name of the file to save to. It then saves the data to a file.

I was told by a colleague what I've done here is very bad. His reasoning is that my code creates the potential for the controller to give the wrong filename to the save method.

I disagree with this because I have unit tests that make sure the filename from the out parameter is the same as the one passed to SaveToFile.

He suggests I just do the save inside of GetPaymentData.

I disagree with this because I think it would be harder to unit test. Currently it is easy to test what's coming back from GetPaymentData is correct but if this method didn't return the data but just save it to a file this would be harder.

Who is right? Is this just a matter of different styles or is someone definitely in the wrong here?

Comment: What on earth does the title have to do with the content?

Comment: Good point will change was from a previous question and didn't get updated

Comment: How is the paymentSummaryFileName generated inside `GeneratePaymentData`? As long as it's not generated from a global static variable inside the `GetPaymentData` method, your colleague's claim is baseless.

Comment: Clearly this is going to be a matter of opinion, which will only solicit debate. If your question contains "better" in it, then there's a good chance that it's not a good fit for SO.

Comment: @Icarus Thanks for your comment. It's not generated from a global static variable. GeneratePaymentData has a generic filename it appends the generation date to.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 that's basically what I was trying to ascertain. Whether what I was doing was actually bad or just a style thing. I did have some difficulty with the title of the question and how to word it so perhaps it needs modifying.

Comment: @user2005657 as long as is not the Date alone what's making the file name unique, there's no problem.

Comment: @Icarus actually it is just the date making it unique. I don't understand why that would be a problem.

Comment: @user2005657 You can have 2 concurrent requests generating the exact same file name even if you go down to the Millisecond field to generate a unique date. Your colleague is still wrong about his claim, though. The problem is not the signature of your method, the problem is that your method to generate a unique file name is flawed if you only rely on date.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote your own unit tests, so you are biased to make the same false assumptions in your test and in your production code. Unit testing is not a holy grail, it is a means to an end.

One way to solve the discussion: ask your colleague to write a unit test that uses your method and fails. You will both learn from it.